# How to find the enclosed charge while figuring out the flux through a closed surface?

Tags: electrostatics

[image]

If suppose I place a charge +Q just outside the hemisphere , why shouldn't we consider the total charge enclosed by the curved surface as Q? Otherwise how to find the enclosed charge to find the flux through the curved surface? I am actually supposed to use the idea of solid angles to find the enclosed charge ,which I am not able to . Can someone help me ?

Comment: If the charge is outside of he surface, the enclosed charge is zero.

Comment: Sir I have placed it just above the surface of the sphere

Answer (score 2):

If you were asked to find the flux through the curved surface from a charge outside, calculate instead the flux through the flat circle at the bottom of the hemisphere.  With no charge inside the hemisphere, the positive flux out through the bottom must be equal in magnitude to the negative flux coming in through the top.